# Cannot fetch ExtendedProperties, existing in an event Android calendar

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

Synchronisation is made between Android calendar and my Exchange account,
initially i have created event from Outlook with extended properties, then when i'm fetching those extended properties in Android calendar using the snippet below:

```
    cursorExtendedProp = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(ExtendedProperties.CONTENT_URI.toString()),new String[] {ExtendedProperties._ID, ExtendedProperties.NAME, ExtendedProperties.VALUE}, null, null, null);   
    while (cursorExtendedProp.moveToNext()) {
         cursorExtendedProp.getString(0);
         cursorExtendedProp.getString(1);
         cursorExtendedProp.getString(2);
    }
    cursorExtendedProp.close();
```

I didn't not get the extended propreties created initially from outlook.
did i miss something ? need some help.

Comment: As far as I know, the extended properties are de-coupled between servers and devices so they don't sync either direction :/

Comment: it's pretty weird how they make it functionned, knowing that userproperties is part of the event...